# EMT radio communications

Tags: united-states, procedure, frequency, emergency

I just joined the community, and I got a communication question. Based on searches most relevant questions were posted in this community, so I hope I can get a proper answer!

EMT, first responders, and ambulance life support use radio communications for emergency crisis management. Can anybody point me to more detailed information about the frequency bands/channels they use, the bandwidth, etc? Seems like they also have multiple levels of priorities associated with them, with multiple level of reliability. Is there any technical documentation that I can use?

Comment: Please consider adding the tag for the country you are asking about. I am guessing probably US, but this is an international site, and US should not be assumed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to add a comment but I don't have enough reputation. I think this is a broad question and will depend on your particular location of interest. I would start checking, specially if you are located in USA, http://www.radioreference.com/apps/db/?coid=1 for the frequencies, type of stations, access code tones, transmission mode, and description of use for EMS/Fire frequencies in any county in the U.S. Hope it helps.

Comment: 155.04000 is actually MHz I believe?

Comment: Yes, it is in MHz.

Answer (score 1):

If you are located in the US, then locate the local ARES group working in your area.  ARES is Amateur Radio Emergency Service and it is a volunteer organization created by the ARRL (see http://arrl.org) that works with local government and non-government emergency services such as EMT, Fire, Rescue, etc.

A local ARES volunteer would be a good person to ask your question.  They should know all of the important frequencies, repeaters, and other communications channels for various services.  Note that these are not open to you (usually) to use for communication but you can listen in.

If you have a "Ham" license then you could join such groups.  You may be able to volunteer without having a ham (amateur radio) license although I do not know about that.